# Weird artifacting results in green gibberish on some applications but everything else is fine?

Tags: pi-4, display, ubuntu

I've seen the following corruption before on programs usually on Raspberry Pi, but it's doing it again and I'd at least like to know the cause. This is Ubuntu 20.04 on a Raspberry pi 4, 4GB edition. I'm writing this on the same machine, so obviously everything else is working. I don't recall what OS version (Ubuntu, Raspbian, version number) I've seen this on before, and it's not always the same machine.

Any idea what causes this? That splash screen on opening Eclipse (the rest of Eclipse and the editor work fine) and any page of the Help app both do this consistently, even after a full reboot and depower, at least with my current installation. (I say any page of the help app; apparently links or something still work, but when the page opens I just get a different internally-consistent pattern of scribbles.)

[image: weird green scribbles are appearing on... I guess certain kinds of mixed text and image displays?]

Comment: Have you tried different hdmi cables?

Comment: I have now, but the issue is still there. I'm somewhat limited to two CanaKit cables since these are microHDMI.

Comment: I would try a different brand hdmi cable. Has your Pi always done this - could be faulty - is it still under warranty? Have you tried another screen?

Comment: What would even cause this? Every other application seems to work, but Help and _that particular screen_ of Eclipse don't. I am not sure if it has always done this or not, but I've had it for about a year now.

Comment: I've tried a different pi, a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 image, and a different HDMI cable. Still just these applications. They have to be doing something weird. As I said earlier, everything else works fine.